# Can i configure a column to be droppable using JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hope I am not asking for too much, but I have a use case where a column currently in use needs to be dropped in the near future. I am wondering if I can handle that now itself.

Here is more info:
Say I have a table like

```
 ID | NAME | PHONE | PHONE_ENC
```

Where PHONE_ENC(encrypted phone no.) is the requirement and is expected to be used going forward. Here once I switch over from using PHONE to PHONE_ENC and migrate old records i would like to remove PHONE column itself.

Is it something I can do without changing DO? here is what it looks like now:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUST")
class Customer {
   @Id
   @Column(name="ID")
   String id;

   @Column(name="NAME")
   String name;

   @Column(name="PHONE")
   String phone;

   @Column(name="PHONE_ENC")
   String encPhone;
}
```

I was hoping if I can configure something like droppable for @Column(name="PHONE")

Comment: JPA simply manages persistence to tables. If you want to drop a column then drop it (and remove any associated field). There is nothing that JPA needs to know in that regards.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No you can't.

Long answer: There might be a way but I strongly advise against it, because it adds lots of complexity for little gain.

You could create an inheritance hierarchy mapped to a single table, with one subclass having the `phone` column and another one having the `phone_enc` column. Of course, you'd also need a discriminator column which you then would update when you update `phone_enc`.